Bootstrapping spline construction
I wonder if we should bootstrap the construction of smoothing splines?
I am modelling a logistic model with smoothing term in brms (and mgcv). When performing Bootstrap, a normal replaced resampling of dataset by convention can lead to destructive error from smooth construction where an insufficient number of data points is provided (raised by mgcv::smooth.construct).
I am therefore thinking of a Bayesian-style Bootstrap (mimicking the implementation of package bayesboot) where, rather than resample the dataset, I sample the weight for each observation, following a Dirichlet distribution and feed it to brms (or mgcv with quasibinomial family). However, looking at the code generated makes me wonder. As the construction of smoothing term effectively still used the full training feature space and not surrogate one, would that cause an underestimation of overoptimism? On the flip side, judging from mgcv code, I think (!!) the construction of s(x) does not depend on outcome y (the smooth coefficients do, the basic functions don’t). Therefore, maybe indeed it makes more sense to not bootstrapping it? But I’m not sure.

Can you provide more explanation as to why you think you need to use bootstrap resampling in the first place?

For model validation.
